# application failed (make Killed)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, kill

I have compiled my `cpp` file via a make file. I have run my file via this make file too.

This multi-thread application uses 99% of CPU as well. I am using `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS` as my OS.

After three days of running, I realized that the application has suddenly stopped and I see this unexpected error message on the terminal.

```
Makefile:: recipe for target 'myMain' failed
make: *** myMain Killed
```

There is not other error message. This application failed with no exception error message. And I am highly confidant about the programs I write (about failing) despite no one is writing a full proof application.

I have never seen message of `make: *** something Killed` before too.

Unfortunately, this is a case which I cannot easily repeat again and again to see what is wrong.

I am wondering if `make` application or `Ubuntu` have any mechanism to kill any application if running for a long time and taking huge amount of resource?

**Update**

Thanks to user *Basile Starynkevitch*, this is the result I received from `dmesg`:

```
[351059.556308] Out of memory: Kill process 2794 (main) score 882 or sacrifice child
[351059.556318] Killed process 2794 (main) total-vm:30432908kB, anon-rss:13530324kB, file-rss:0kB
```

Comment: Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug your application. You might also limit the memory (e.g. using `ulimit` builtin of your bash shell)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, what you are saying is great. However, it is a very hard process to run this application again and let it run for a few days until it crashed. `dmesg` has already shown what I should fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely that your program was the victim of the Linux kernel's [OOM Killer](http://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/).  See also this [question and answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short).

Comment: Use also `dmesg`  and look into `/var/log/` files, notably `syslog` and `messages`

Comment: I am wondering why my application uses such huge amount of RAM. There is no memory leakage as it follows C++ guide lines.

Comment: Also, I am wondering how make realizes that this process is killed and not terminated by its own.

Comment: Maybe post a new question if you have more questions. Obviously your application uses a lot of memory but perhaps that is by design and not leakage.

Comment: The reason for a process dying is visible to the parent process (in this case `make`).  The value the parent receives when the child dies encodes information such as the exit code (if it exited normally), the signal it received that caused it to die, whether it dumped core, etc.  So, make knows that the process died because it was killed by a SIGKILL (9), which is how the OOM Killer kills things.

Answer (score 0):

> Out of memory: Kill process

Most likely you were compiling sources as a user and your environment were restricted by the resource limits listed with `ulimit -a` command (either memory or number of processes). Once the hard limit is hit, the process is killed by the Linux kernel.

If you've got enough memory, it's possible to increase these limits (`ulimit -Sv`), otherwise you need to increase memory of your machine or add some [extra swap space](https://askubuntu.com/q/33697/78223).

For more details about this behaviour, see: [Kernel - Out Of Memory Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html).

> When the machine is low on memory, old page frames will be reclaimed, but despite reclaiming pages is may find that it was unable to free enough pages to satisfy a request even when scanning at highest priority. If it does fail to free page frames, `out_of_memory()` is called to see if the system is out of memory and needs to kill a process.